# Login on existing Putty session on main server

Tags: session, ubuntu, authentication, putty

I have a minecraft server running ubuntu server. What i've been doing so far is using putty to create a new session on my PC. The problem is that eventually like most human beings I go to sleep, and do not like having my PC left on cuz of the noise. If i turn off my PC obviously that session will end and the server will go down. What I want to do is create a session on the main server(not my PC), and use putty to control that existing session(from my PC). This way even if I turn off my PC the server will still be running in the other room. I appreciate any feedback. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is referred to as a daemon in UNIX. The standard way to manage daemons is through the init system. The init system has been around for a very long time and has diverged quite a bit between BSD, Solaris, and the various Linux Distros.

All the init systems provide the same basic functionality. The init system manages long running processes which are not tied to a user login. They are frequently used for managing server oriented processes, such as web servers.

Where the init systems differ is in their usage and the features they provide. Ubuntu uses an init replacement called upstart and it is very well documented.

You could write the needed upstart scripts yourself, but a quick search provides plenty of upstart scripts other people have created for minecraft that you could use instead.

http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Ubuntu_startup_script

Comment: Ahhh i c. i will check it out, and report back. Thanks for your help so far. :)

Comment: I made a minor mistake, they are typically called "daemons" not "services", but you could mostly use the terms interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net) or [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Comment: While it might work, this is a horrible solution to the problem.

Comment: Then it sounds like you have a somewhat different interpretation of the problem than I do.

Comment: What he is describing is a service. This is what the init system was designed for. Running a service in a screen session is quick hack that isn't a very robust or long term solution.

Comment: I encourage you to add another answer that describes your solution to the question.

Comment: I would not criticize without providing a better path.